# Dismiss navigation view when Core Data object is deleted

Tags: swift, macos, core-data, swiftui

I'm attempting to use SwiftUI and CoreData to build a macOS application. This application's main window has a `NavigationView`, with list items bound to a fetch request, and selecting any of these items populates the detail view. The navigation view goes kind of like this:

```
NavigationView {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        List(fetchRequest) { DetailRow(model: $0) }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())

        HStack {
            Button(action: add) { Text("+") }
            Button(action: remove) { Text("-") }
        }
    }

    Text("Select a model object")
}.navigationViewStyle(DoubleColumnNavigationViewStyle())
```

`DetailRow` is a `NavigationLink` that also defines the detail view:

```
NavigationLink(destination: ModelDetail(model: model)) {
    Text(model.name)
}
```

I believe that the contents of `ModelDetail` isn't very important; either way, I'm fairly flexible with it.

In the navigation view, the "-" button, which calls the `remove` method, should delete the currently-selected model object and return to the default, empty detail view. Unfortunately, I'm struggling to come up with the right way to do this. I believe that I need the following interactions to happen:

1. subview communicates to navigation view which model object is currently selected
2. user clicks "-" button, navigation view's `remove` method deletes currently selected object
3. subview notices that its model object is being deleted
4. → subview calls `PresentationMode.dismiss()`

Step 3 is the one I'm struggling with. Everything is working out alright so far without using view-model classes on top of the Core Data classes, but I feel stuck trying to figure out how to get the subview to call `dismiss()`. This needs to happen from the detail view, because it gets the `PresentationMode` from the environment, and the `NavigationView` changes it.

While I can get a `Binding` to the model's `isDeleted` property through `@ObservedObject`, I don't know how I can actually react to that change; `Binding` appears to use publishers under the hood, but they don't expose a publisher that I could hook up to with `onPublish`, for instance.

KVO over `isDeleted` might be possible, but listening from a value type isn't great; there's no good place to remove the observer, which could become problematic were the app to run for too long.

What's the guidance for this type of problem?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Heres my solution.

This is my `NoteDetailView`. It allows deletion from this view, or the "master" view in the Navigation hierarchy. This solution works on Mac, iPad, and iPhone.

I added an optional `dateDeleted` to my Entity. When a record is deleted, I simply add a value of `Date()` to this attribute and save the context. In my FetchRequests, I simply predicate for `dateDeleted = nil`. I'm going to add a trash can and stuff to my app later so people can view or permanently empty their trash.

Then I use a state variable and a notification to clear my View. You can change the code up for the functionality you want:

```
struct NoteDetailView: View {
    var note: Note
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var managedObjectContext
    @State var noteBody: String = ""
    @State var showEditNoteView: Bool = false
    @State var showEmptyView: Bool = false

    init(note: Note) {
        self.note = note
        self._noteBody = State(initialValue: note.body)
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if (!showEmptyView) {
                Text("NOT DELETED")
            }
            else {
                EmptyView()
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(!showEmptyView ? note.title : "")
        .navigationBarItems(trailing:
            HStack {
                if (!showEmptyView) {
                    Button(action: {
                        self.showEditNoteView.toggle()
                    }, label: {
                        NavBarImage(image: "pencil")
                    })
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showEditNoteView, content: {
                        EditNoteView(note: self.note).environment(\.managedObjectContext, self.managedObjectContext)
                    })
                }
            }
        )
        .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .NSManagedObjectContextDidSave)) { _ in
            if (self.note.dateDeleted != nil) {
                self.showEmptyView = true
                self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
            }
        }
    }
}
```